# I have tried putting display: inline-block in every scenario and I can't get it to cross the top of the page . .

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a NAV bar and I have tried putting 'display: inline-block;' in every single element but for the life of me it won't cross the whole page. Any idea's? I want to have my logo in the center of the navigation bar with the other links centered across the rest of the top of the page. It doesn't matter where I put the 'display: inline-block;' it never centers it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gingerich Tiling</title>
    <link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="nav1">
            <div class="left-nav-bar">
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
               </ul>
             </div>
              <div class="logo">
                    <li><a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="Images/Gingerich%20Final%20Logo.jpg" alt ="Gingerich Tiling Logo" height="250" width="300"</a></li>
              </div>
              <div class=right-nav-bar>
                  <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Tiling</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Earthmoving</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Septic</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>
</html>

    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
}

body {
    
}

header {
   text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav1 {
    align-content: center;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {

}

.nav1 li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.left-nav-bar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.logo { 
}
.right-nav-bar {
     margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the question, I think I got how you want it to look. The problem was that you were using `inline-block` a bit too much, actually!

You can achieve the look using `display: flex` (`display: grid` would also work, but I think flex layout is more straight-forward in this case) in conjunction with `justify-content: space-evenly` on your `<nav>` element.

Please also note that you cannot have a `<li>` element anywhere other than as a direct child element of a `<ul>` (that was not the case with your logo!)

Once you add a little padding to the sides of your navigation links, it should look good.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
}

body {}

header nav {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.nav1 {
  align-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 0.3em;
}

nav ul {}

.nav1 li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.left-nav-bar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  width: 48px;
}

.right-nav-bar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="nav1">
    <div class="left-nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
        <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="//placekitten.com/48/48" alt="Gingerich Tiling Logo" height="48" width="48"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class=right-nav-bar>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tiling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Earthmoving</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Septic</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of unnecessary containers. But I didn't change the HTML but I did change your CSS. The best way to make navigation is by using `display: flex;`. They are easy to use and very effective.
Here is the CSS, just copy-paste this and see if you like the result :)

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
}

/* body {

} */

header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.nav1 {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* nav ul {

} */

.nav1 li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.left-nav-bar,
.right-nav-bar {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.left-nav-bar ul,
.right-nav-bar ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    row-gap: 20px;
}
```